# how to use jsPDF and jspdf-autotable in angular 5

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to use jsPDF and jspdf-autotable in my Angular 5.2.0 project. My package.json is below (related parts):

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "jspdf": "^1.3.5",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^2.3.2"
    ...
}
```

My angular-cli.json is below (related parts):

```
"scripts": [
    ...
    "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
    "../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"
    ...
  ]
```

My component (related parts ):

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';

@Component({
    selector: "energy-login",
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./login.component.scss"]
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    downloadPDF() {

        let columns = ["ID", "Name", "Country"];
        let rows = [
            [1, "Shaw", "Tanzania"],
            [2, "Nelson", "Kazakhstan"],
            [3, "Garcia", "Madagascar"],
        ];

        let doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt');
        doc.autoTable(columns, rows); // typescript compile time error
        doc.save('table.pdf');
    }
}
```

It says:

```
[ts] Property 'autoTable' does not exist on type 'jsPDF'.
```

I tried to replace imports in my component with

```
// import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
// import 'jspdf-autotable';
declare var jsPDF: any;
```

then there is no compile time error but while running downloadPDF() function it says :

```
ERROR ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with jspdf-autotable in angular 5, one must install jspdf and jspdf-autotable via npm

```
npm install jspdf-autotable --save
```

also add the jspdf and jspdf-autotable files to the scripts array in angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
    "../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"
],
```

and in component never import jspdf or jspdf-autotable just

```
declare var jsPDF: any;
```

Of course before working with jspdf-autotable one should install jspdf and for development @types/jspdf via npm

```
npm install jspdf --save
npm install @types/jspdf --save-dev
```

Answer (score 15):

**Is working for me Angular 5.**

To work with jspdf-autotable in **angular 5**, one must install jspdf and jspdf-autotable via npm

```
npm install jspdf --save
npm install @types/jspdf --save-dev
npm install jspdf-autotable --save
```

also add the jspdf and jspdf-autotable files to the scripts array in angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
"../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
"../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"
],
```

and in component never import jspdf or jspdf-autotable just.

**Forget about the following import.**

```
    import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'; 
    import 'jspdf-autotable';
```

Just use Before @Component:

```
declare var jsPDF: any;
```

Your component (related parts ):

```
declare var jsPDF: any;

@Component({
    selector: "energy-login",
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./login.component.scss"]
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    downloadPDF() {

        let columns = ["ID", "Name", "Country"];
        let rows = [
            [1, "Shaw", "Tanzania"],
            [2, "Nelson", "Kazakhstan"],
            [3, "Garcia", "Madagascar"],
        ];

        let doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt');
        doc.autoTable(columns, rows); // typescript compile time error
        doc.save('table.pdf');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Alciomar Hollanda, It help me a lot.

Comment: On my end, I get the error "ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined"

Answer (score 10):

I was able to please TypeScript like this:

```js
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
import { UserOptions } from 'jspdf-autotable';

interface jsPDFWithPlugin extends jsPDF {
  autoTable: (options: UserOptions) => jsPDF;
}
...
const doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'px', 'a4') as jsPDFWithPlugin;
doc.autoTable({
  head: [['Name', 'Email', 'Country']],
  body: [
    ['David', 'david@example.com', 'Sweden'],
    ['Castille', 'castille@example.com', 'Norway']
  ]
});
```

Works in Angular 7 (also works in Angular 14)

Comment: This is the cleanest solution. Not sure why doesn't have a lot of votes

Comment: This work really well and provides clear and logical documentation, especially the typing.

Comment: Instead of using "import * as jsPDF", I simply used "import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';"

Answer (score 5):

I'm using angular 7, and just `declare var jsPDF: any;` doesn't work to me. After some googling, the solution was:

```
declare const require: any;
const jsPDF = require('jspdf');
require('jspdf-autotable');
```

And of course, I installed the modules from npm and include them into the scripts array in angular.json. It works fine to me.

Comment: Man, converting HTML to PDF should be a trivial task. Thanks for this! This is awesome.

Comment: That solved the problem, This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This made my day

Answer (score 3):

In angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js"
  ],
```

In your project

```
import * as jsPdf from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
```

This work for me

Answer (score 2):

First you have declared `.js` files in `styles` property in `angular-cli.json`, you should add them to `scripts`. In the configuration that you have, you should add your `jspdf` scripts to `scripts` in `angular-cli.json`, So:

```
"scripts": [ 
    "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
    "../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"
  ],
```

then you don't have to import any `jspdf` to your component. `declare var jsPdf: any` will be enough to use it.

Comment: thank you. Your right .js files should be declared in scripts array, and I actually declared them in there - fixed it in the question. My previous attempt was installing dependencies via npm. That is why my dependencies object in package.json includes "jspdf": "^1.3.5",  "jspdf-autotable": "^2.3.2" also devDependencies object includes "@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31".  Anyway i solved my problem. Answering my question below.

Answer (score 1):

If you could use **declare var jsPDF: any;** it is working for Chrome, IE and other browsers too, but it is not working for Firefox browser.

In this case, you could follow the below steps:

```
declare const require: any;
const jsPDF = require('jspdf');
require('jspdf-autotable');
```

and other parts remain same like:

```
npm install jspdf --save
npm install @types/jspdf --save-dev
npm install jspdf-autotable --save
```

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
    "../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"
],
```

So, it will defiantly work on all the browsers.
how simple it is :)

Answer (score 1):

### In my case //@ts-ignore worked....

```
//@ts-ignore
doc.autoTable(this.exportColumns, this.exportData);
doc.save('filename.pdf');
```

If your code is running perfectly but showing autotable error during ng serve and ng build, then //@ts-ignore will work for you to ignore error check during ng serve and ng build.
Just put //@ts-ignore above the line which is showing error.

Comment: you are correct, it's working for me too. Could you please explain to me the working on //@ts-ignore, and how it is solving the error? It would be really helpful for further issues if any of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, first import the Jspdf import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
i'm used a codesmells tatic, copied the content of jspdf autotable and pasted inside
the jspdf.js, then works fine for me.

in the official site said you have to use //declare var jsPDF: any; // Important . it doesnt work in  my case, try import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'; instead.

in angular.json  in scripts :

"./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
 "./node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js",

Answer (score 0):

## Angular 8 +

This is how i did in Angular 8 please check below example which generate fake user using faker service, you can change it with your `API` response.

Install packages via npm

```js
npm i jspdf jspdf-autotable faker --save
```

Install types

```js
npm install @types/jspdf  @types/faker --save-dev
```

add below entries into angular.json

```ts
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
              "node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"
            ]
```

component.ts

```ts
import * as faker from 'faker'; // Not really require by jspdf or jsPDF-AutoTable 
declare var jsPDF: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'faker',
  templateUrl: './faker.component.html',
})


export class FakerPDFGeneratorComponent {



 headRows() {
    return [{id: 'ID', name: 'Name', email: 'Email', city: 'City', expenses: 'Sum'}];
  }

    footRows() {
    return [{id: 'ID', name: 'Name', email: 'Email', city: 'City', expenses: 'Sum'}];
  }

   bodyRows(rowCount) {
    rowCount = rowCount || 10;
    let body = [];
    for (var j = 1; j <= rowCount; j++) {
      body.push({
        id: j,
        name: faker.name.findName(),
        email: faker.internet.email(),
        city: faker.address.city(),
        expenses: faker.finance.amount(),
      });
    }
    return body;
  }

createPdf() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.setFontSize(18);
    doc.text('With content', 14, 22);
    doc.setFontSize(11);
    doc.setTextColor(100);

    // jsPDF 1.4+ uses getWidth, <1.4 uses .width
    var pageSize = doc.internal.pageSize;
    var pageWidth = pageSize.width ? pageSize.width : pageSize.getWidth();
    var text = doc.splitTextToSize(faker.lorem.sentence(45), pageWidth - 35, {});
    doc.text(text, 14, 30);

    doc.autoTable({
      head: this.headRows(),
      body: this.bodyRows(40),
      startY: 50,
      showHead: 'firstPage'
    });

    doc.text(text, 14, doc.autoTable.previous.finalY + 10);

    doc.save('table.pdf');
  }

}
```

### Go ahead and play around with code and demo

[image: Edit Angular]

Answer (score -1):

Declare doc as any type. That will fix the error "[ts] Property 'autoTable' does not exist on type 'jsPDF'."

let doc:any = new jsPDF('l', 'pt');